# How to use LLVM test-suite to test my custom pass?

Tags: llvm

I am a Master's student working on an optimization pass on LLVM IR to validate some of my ideas. I currently use a simple script I wrote to test my pass. However, I think it is better to use an existing testing infrastructure. After searching, I find the LLVM test-suite might fit my need. But after reading [test-suite guide](https://llvm.org/docs/TestSuiteGuide.html) and some related posts on Stack Overflow, I still have no idea about how to test my custom pass with `lit`.

I develop my pass out of source, and below is roughly what my script does.

1. Compile each source file into the corresponding LLVM IR file.
2. Use `llvm-link` to link all IR files into one.
3. Run my pass on the IR file.
4. Use `llc` to generate the object file.
5. Use `clang` to generate the executable.

I wonder if it is possible to have `lit` follow the above steps to generate the executable and run the test. If so, how can I achieve this? In fact, I suspect that maybe what I want to do is not relevant to `lit`, but don't know what to start with.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks!